# Can't modify html file with python script

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm attempting to change the text of certain  elements with specific ID in my HTML file. Despite running the code without any reported errors, the classes' content remains unchanged, and the modifications do not take effect.

Also when I run my code it say Saved correctly and HTML file successfully updated.

html code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="mt-n6 bg-white mb-10 rounded-3 shadow-sm p-lg-10 p-5">
                <div class="mb-8">
                    <!DOCTYPE html>
                    <html>
                    <head>
                        <title>
                            Display HTML Inside iFrame
                        </title>
                        <style>
                            #iframeBox {
                                border: 2px solid #ccc;
                                width: 100%; /* You can adjust the width as needed */
                                height: 400px; /* You can adjust the height as needed */
                            }
                        </style>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                    <div class="center-container" style="text-align: center; margin-bottom: 10px">
                        <label for="iframeBox" style="font-weight: bold">
                            <h3 style="color: black">
                                Veuillez signer le
                                contrat ci-dessous
                            </h3>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <iframe frameborder="0" id="iframeBox">
                    </iframe>
                    <script>
                        // Get the iframe element
                        const iframeBox = document.getElementById('iframeBox');

                        // Set the content of the iframe to your HTML code
                        iframeBox.contentDocument.open();
                        iframeBox.contentDocument.write(`
            <body class="c35 doc-content">
<div><p class="c20"><span class="c1 c26">        - </span><span class="c1 c26"> -</span><span
        style="overflow: hidden; display: inline-block; margin: 0.00px 0.00px; border: 0.00px solid #000000; transform: rotate(0.00rad) translateZ(0px); -webkit-transform: rotate(0.00rad) translateZ(0px); width: 97.33px; height: 97.33px;"></span>
</p></div>
<p class="c19"><span class="c13 c24">CONTRAT DE PRÊT</span></p>
<p class="c4 c18"><span class="c1 c0"></span></p>
<p class="c4"><span class="c0">INTERVENU LE </span><span class="c0 c16" id="date1">___ AVRIL 2023</span><span class="c0">, À</span>
</p>
<p class="c4 c11 c18"><span class="c1 c0"></span></p>
<p class="c4 c11"><span class="c0">ENTRE:        .</span><span class="c2">, constituée en vertu de la </span><span
        class="c2 c30">Loi canadienne sur les sociétés par actions)</span><span class="c2"> ayant son siège social au 3, </span><span
        class="c2 c12">dûment représentée par, sa présidente, et , sa Vice-Présidente</span><span
        class="c2"> </span><span class="c1 c0">;</span></p>
<p class="c28"><span class="c2">        (ci-après dénommée, le « </span><span class="c0">Prêteur</span><span
        class="c1 c2"> »)</span></p>
<p class="c4 c32"><span class="c0">ET :        [</span><span class="c0 c16" id="nom1">INSÉRER LE NOM</span><span
```

and here is my python code

```
def update_html_file(file_path, date_text, nom_text):
    with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        html_content = file.read()

    # Parse the HTML content using Beautiful Soup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')

    # Find the element with the id 'date1' and update its text
    date_element = soup.find('span', {'id': 'date1'})
    if date_element:
        date_element.string = date_text

    # Find the element with the id 'nom1' and update its text
    nom_element = soup.find('span', {'id': 'nom1'})
    if nom_element:
        nom_element.string = nom_text

    # Return the updated HTML content
    updated_html = soup.prettify()

    # Write the updated HTML content back to the file
    with open(file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.write(updated_html)


# Provide the path to your HTML file
html_file_path = 'templates/main/contrat_template.html'

# Provide the new text for date1 and nom1
new_date_text = 'NEW DATE TEXT'
new_nom_text = 'NEW NOM TEXT'

# Update the HTML content and save to the file
update_html_file(html_file_path, new_date_text, new_nom_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that you are trying to modify the HTML content inside an iframe using `BeautifulSoup`, but this approach won't work. When you use an **iframe** to embed another HTML document, the content inside the **iframe** is considered a **separate document**, and you can't directly modify it from the parent document using Python libraries like BeautifulSoup because it doesn't deal with *dynamically generated content* (as in generated by `Javascript`)

---

Your option would be to use a library like `Selenium` since it can be more interactive.

Install it with

```
pip install selenium
```

Here's an example

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

def update_html_file(file_path, date_text, nom_text):
    # Create a browser instance (e.g., Chrome)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    # Load the URL
    driver.get(file_path)

    # Switch to the iframe 
    driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.ID, 'iframeBox'))

    # Find the element inside the iframe and change its value
    target_element = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'date1')
    target_element.send_keys(date_text)

    # Find the element inside the iframe and change its value
    target_element = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'nom1')
    target_element.send_keys(nom_text)

    # Write the updated HTML content to the file
    with open(file_path, 'w') as f:
        f.write(driver.page_source)

    # Close the browser
    driver.quit()

# Provide the path to your HTML file
html_file_path = r'C:\test\index.html'

# Provide the new text for date1 and nom1
new_date_text = 'NEW DATE TEXT'
new_nom_text = 'NEW NOM TEXT'

# Update the HTML content and save to the file
update_html_file(html_file_path, new_date_text, new_nom_text)
```

Comment: thanks you, any idea how can i fix that?

Comment: @tiberhockey I have updated the answer, couldn't test it because your HTML has some issues and unclosed tags.